# How do I use bcrypt in rails and validate the password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

Because rails clears the errors during save, I can't do this in my model:

```
  def password= plain_text
    if plain_text =~ /\d/ && plain_text =~ /\w/
      self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(plain_text)
    else
      self.errors[:password] = "must contain one digit and one word character."
    end
  end
```

What's the best way to validate a password to have one letter and one digit in rails, while still using bcrypt?

Comment: did you look into this http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/

Comment: I did, it mentions nothing of validating password formats before hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Rails [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) option, then Rails will handle the `password=` method for you.  When you set the password [Rails will hold onto the unencrypted password in the instance variable `@password`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L118):

```rb
def password=(unencrypted_password)
  ...
  @password = unencrypted_password
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
  self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(unencrypted_password, cost: cost)
```

The `@password` value will remain in memory until the record is saved to the database.  So you can run validations against `password`.  When validations pass, the encrypted `password_digest` value is what will be stored.

You can see that this is what Rails does when they [validate that the password isn't longer than the largest password allowed](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L79):

```rb
validates_length_of :password, maximum: ActiveModel::SecurePassword::MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH_ALLOWED
```